# Got error when running application in Railway: no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/12WeekMethod-plain.jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, railway

`I am encountering an issue while attempting to deploy my application in Railway. Locally, the application runs without any problems. However, during the deployment process in Railway, I keep encountering the following error message:

no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/12WeekMethod-plain.jar

This is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.13'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.mundim'
version = ''

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.1'
    implementation 'org.testng:testng:7.1.0'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    // Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    // Swagger
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0'
    // Security
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:3.1.1'
    // Thymeleaf
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:3.1.1.RELEASE'
    // JJWT
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:4.2.1'
    // Mail sender
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // Thymeleaf
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.1.1.RELEASE'

    // Test
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.2.220'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Try set the property of task ‘Jar'. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar.html#org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar:manifest

Comment: Remove the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` dependencies and stop mixing versions of Spring Boot. You are mixing 2.7.13 and 3.1.1. that is not going to work, never mix modules from different versions of a framework. Remove the version for the `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency. Remove the thymeleaf dependencies and add `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` instead. Also why is `testng` an `implemnetation` sopced dependency? Should that be a `testImplementation` or removed as you seem to use JUnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your dependencies are a mess. You are including incompatible versions and are mixing modules from different versions of a framework. Here you are mixing Spring Boot 2.7.x and 3.1.x that is never going to work nor is something you should never do.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.13'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.mundim'
version = ''

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'

    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    // Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    // Swagger
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0'
   
    // JJWT
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:4.2.1'
    // Mail sender
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    // Test
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.2.220'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

- Removed `testng` and `junit` dependency as you seem to be using JUnit Jupiter (judging from the test setup).
- Removed version from the `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies so the versions align
- Removed version from `org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` so it uses a compatible version (managed by Spring Boot)
- Replaced Thymeleaf with `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` to get the proper version and management.

With this you should have proper and compatible versions and your application will start.

Finally you should use `./gradlew build` to build a jar and not use the `plain` one as that doesn't include the dpendencies. You need to deploy the fatjar created by Spring Boot.